# Prove that in every acute triangle, the equation stands: $h_c = c \cfrac{\tan(\alpha)\cdot \tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)} $

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Prove that in every acute triangle, the equation stands: $$h_c = c \cfrac{\tan(\alpha)\cdot \tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)} $$

Comment: Can you tell us something about what you have tried?

Comment: you have three angles $\alpha,\beta$ and $\pi-\alpha-\beta$. That should be enough to start the process (if you did not start with this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \tan(\alpha) &=& \frac{h_c}{c_1},\\\\
> \tan(\beta) &=& \frac{h_c}{c_2},\\\\
> c &=& c_1 + c_2.
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$

Then

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> c &=& \frac{h_c}{\tan(\alpha)} + \frac{h_2}{\tan(\beta)}\\\\
> &=& h_c \frac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$

Whence

> $$
> h_c = c \frac{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}
> $$